# How to formulate this SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get the `employee numbers` and `start dates` of all the employees with `start dates` equal to the earliest date.

I know this is wrong. But just writing to show what I want.

```
SELECT     start_date, employee_no
FROM         [employees]
WHERE     (start_date = MIN(start_date))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You were close!

```
SELECT     start_date, employee_no
FROM         [employees]
WHERE     start_date = (SELECT MIN(start_date) FROM employees)
```

Comment: you type just that much faster, all yours

Comment: @DevelopingChris - I just copied and pasted his and made it correct! :)

Comment: there must have been 5 of us typing it out when you posted.

Comment: It looks that way :)  Low hanging fruit gets picked quickest.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use a Common Expression Table (CTE) to do this. It's like creating a temp table.

```
;with EmpInfo as 
(
    SELECT start_date, employee_no, MIN(start_date) OVER () as MinStartDate
    FROM [employees]
)
SELECT start_date, employee_no FROM EmpInfo WHERE start_date = MinStartDate
```

Here's a Microsoft web page about [Using Common Table Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx)

Comment: The performance is slightly better as well according the the Execution Plan. We have a very similar table of employee data, so I was able to compare plans easily. :)

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
SELECT     start_date, employee_no 
FROM         [employees] 
WHERE     start_date = (select MIN(start_date) from [employees])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT    start_date, employee_no
FROM      [employees]
WHERE     start_date = (SELECT MIN(start_date) FROM [employees])
```